# java applications architecture data exchange

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

we are developing more java applications. Very simple descriptions.

1. frontend applications - web app, interact with users
2. middleware app - provide some functionality for frontend app
3. transport app - app which communicates with external systems.

These applications communicate with each other through xml transport over http. 
Scenario from real life looks like, user create some action in frontend app, frontend app calls 
middleware app, and usually middleware app calls transport app (which usually calls some other external system).
Also frontend app could call directly transport app, it depends on flow and business logic etc.
Like you see there are plenty of http calls, frontend app create http call and call middleware app and, middleware app create 
http call and call transport app, transport asks some other system and send response back to middleware etc.

My question is. Is this really good architecture? Looks like too much overhead to me. There should be some other better solution, 
how to transport data between apps, even they are running in one server.

Data are in 99% simple xml's, created through xstream.
Could be JMS appropriate solution for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that although it will most certainly work OK, the approach with http calls between layers is probably a bit heavy-handed.

JMS would be a very good match if the calls between the different layers are asynchronous and essentially fire and forget (you fire a message and aren't immediately interested in the outcome of the work the destination has to do when it receives your message).  Although there are people who do request-reply with JMS I don't feel it's the most natural and elegant usage of a message oriented system.

If what you're doing is synchronous (you call a backend and wait for it to respond to your request) I'd go with normal (stateless) session beans, the creation and management of those has been simplified a lot in EE6.

Another advantage with EJB's is that you don't incur the overhead of the different XML serializations and deserializations that are needed in the scenario you describe.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Our calls are synchronous, so JMS is not the choice then. Problem with EJB is, we have all our applications based on Spring/Hibernate approach.

Comment: @user1250015 unless you're running on a pure servletcontainer like Jetty or Tomcat that shouldn't be a problem, Spring and EJB3.1 should be capable of working together as far as I know...

Comment: We are running on weblogic server, so far i understood, it should work